# Implementing countbyenumeratingwithstate for custom UICollectionviewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, loops, for-loop, uicollectionview

I am building an app with a CollectionView filled with custom CollectionViewCell.

I added a button "select all/deselect all" which is obviously supposed to affect all the cell in my collectionView. To do this I intended to use a for-loop like this:

```
for(customCollectionViewCell* cell in self.collectionView){  
    // some code
}
```

However i first get a warning saying:

```
Collection expression type "UICollectionView *" many not correspond to "countByEnumeratingWithStage:objects:count"
```

And when I compile the program and click on the button, the app crash with the following error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionView countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7973e00'
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't iterate the collection view itself, but rather the array of cells it returns by calling the `visibleCells` method on it.